# CMIS desktop clients?

Tags: cmis

Below is a screenshot of "CMIS Explorer", it is a program that allows desktop users to browse through a [CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) documents repository.

Do you know other CMIS desktop client programs?
I am especially looking for one that allows check-in/check-out of documents (not implemented in CMIS Explorer yet), but any other would be appreciated too.

[image: CMIS Explorer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at [OpenCMIS Workbench](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/chemistry-opencmis-workbench/0.6.0/chemistry-opencmis-workbench-0.6.0-full.zip).

Comment: Nice tool indeed! Glad to see it has Checkout/Checkin buttons, even though I receive errors when trying them (bug reported).

Comment: URL is now broken, this one works: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/chemistry-opencmis-workbench/0.6.0/chemistry-opencmis-workbench-0.6.0-full.zip

Answer (score 1):

[LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) has now added this functionality with version 4.  Enabling the checking in, editing, and checking out of supported documents.  There's a YouTube video demonstrating these features; [Demonstration of LibreOffice 4.0 with CMIS integration (English)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2bbnyAjMeM)